# ggplot side by side geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a side by side barplot using geom_bar() of this data frame,

```
> dfp1
   value   percent1   percent
1 (18,29] 0.20909091 0.4545455
2 (29,40] 0.23478261 0.5431034
3 (40,51] 0.15492958 0.3661972
4 (51,62] 0.10119048 0.1726190
5 (62,95] 0.05660377 0.1194969
```

With values on the x-axis and the percents as the side by side barplots. I have tried using this code,

```
p = ggplot(dfp1, aes(x = value, y= c(percent, percent1)), xlab="Age Group")
p = p + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5)
```

However, I get this error: Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:value. My percent and percent1 are the same length as value, so I am confused. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You will need to `melt` your data first over `value`. It will create another variable called `value` by default, so you will need to renames it (I called it `percent`). Then, plot the new data set using `fill` in order to separate the data into groups, and `position = "dodge"` in order put the bars side by side (instead of on top of each other)

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
dfp1 <- melt(dfp1)
names(dfp1)[3] <- "percent"
ggplot(dfp1, aes(x = value, y= percent, fill = variable), xlab="Age Group") +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use the geom_text(aes(x=, y=, label=mylabels) option with dodge bars in order to get a label centered on each bar?

Answer (score 6):

Similar to David's answer, here is a tidyverse option using `tidyr::pivot_longer` to reshape the data before plotting:

```
library(tidyverse)

dfp1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-value, names_to = "variable", values_to = "percent") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = percent, fill = variable), xlab="Age Group") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to order the value (abscissa) by the SUM of the percents?

Comment: What does `xlab = "Age Group"` do?

Comment: @Caddisfly it suppose to set the label of the x axis. But it should be xlab("Age Group")