# ggmosaic plot with asymmetric offset

Tags: r, ggmosaic

I have a mosaic plot generated by `ggmosaic`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(a1=c(T,T,F,F), a2=c(T,F,T,F), a3=c(1,3,3,3))) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(weight=a3, x=product(a1,a2), fill=a1))
```

[image: mosaic plot]

I would like to widen the space between the vertical bars without changing the height of the space between the stacked columns:

[image: wide mosaic plot]

I've tried using the `offset` parameter, but it seems to work on both dimensions, and can't isolate just one. An answer using vanilla `ggplot` is acceptable, but a `ggmosaic`-only solution is preferred.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you will not be able to accomplish this via `geom_mosaic()`. Only can do this via `geom_bar()`. There is no `width =` option within `geom_mosaic()`.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25070645/5874001

Answer (score 0):

A less-than-ideal workaround using using `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(a1=c(T,T,F,F), a2=c(T,F,T,F), a3=c(1,3,3,3)), aes(width=c(.4,.6,.4,.6)))+
   geom_bar(aes(x=a2, y=-a3, fill=a1), position = "fill", stat = "identity")
```

[image: bar mosaic]