# Formatting A double Bar Chart from Created from A Single DataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having issues formatting a double bar chart so that the bars appear next to each-other, rather than stacked. As you'll see, I am trying and failing to implement a dodge.

Here's a sample of my dataframe called combinedCountFrame:

```
             system n.x n.y
1            T-64BV   7  65
2             T-72A   8   0
3            T-72AV   3   2
4             T-72B  47   2
5   T-72B Obr. 1989  13   0
6            T-72B3  30   0
7  T-72B3 Obr. 2016  70   0
8            T-80BV  11   3
9           T-80BVM  18   0
10            T-80U  44   0
11           T-80UK   2   0
12          T-80UM2   1   0
13            T-90A  17   0
14     Unknown tank  25   1
15          T-64B1M   0   1
16          T-72AMT   0   3
```

Here's my code for the plot:

```
ggplot(combinedCountFrame, aes(x = system)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = n.x, fill = "Russia"), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = n.y, fill = "Ukraine"), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
    labs(
      title = paste(equipmentType, "Losses", sep = " "),
      y = "# of Systems Lost",
      fill = "Country"
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
      legend.position = "top",
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
    )
```

Here's the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: Or this answer may provide better help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713309/12109788

Comment: @jpsmith Awesome! Thank you this was very helpful

Comment: There is something off with your data, where is the column that include Russia and Ukraine? The fill should include the column which include Russia and Ukraine for this to work? change the fill to Country and you will get two bars for each n.x and two bars for each n.y.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my code using the steps in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713309/12109788

Thanks to jpsmith for showing me that link.

Here's my implemented fix:

```
combinedCountFrame <- melt(combinedCountFrame)
names(combinedCountFrame)[3] <- "totals"

ggplot(combinedCountFrame,aes(x=system, y = totals, fill=variable))+
       geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, position = "dodge") +  
       labs(fill = "Country") +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]